# Access to the web application denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio

I'm working on a project on visual studio, mvc with c # language. this project was passed to me by a colleague of mine and the problem is that when I try to log in I can't. checking it several times I think the problem is on the angular controller. in fact when I try to log in I get "err" running even though I enter the correct data. the mistake that gives me is this: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED [http://localhost:1336/token]".

```
LoginController.prototype.doLogin = function(){
    var that = this;
    this.authService.login(this.vm.username, this.vm.password).then(
        function(response) {
            that.layoutService.gotoHome();
        }, function(err) {
            that.vm.hasInvalidData = true;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This is a english forum only. If you can translate for sure you'll get some help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is nothing running on port 1336 of your local machine, thus causing the Angular AJAX call to fail. Make sure that you configure your MVC project in Visual Studio to listen on port 1336 and that it is set up as the Start-up project.

Comment: so can it be a problem with my computer? because on my colleague's computer the project works

Comment: Not your computer, but the settings for the project on your computer. Visual Studio allows settings per user or per project for web applications at least.

Comment: but in the properties of the project is set '1336' as a door. it's two days I'm stuck :(

Comment: In this case, it could be any number of things: you are not starting the web application that listens on port 1336, your anti-virus or firewall blocks 1336, your IT has a policy to block certain ports, etc. It is difficult to troubleshoot without being in situ.